# JVM reuse does not improve benchmark performance time in Hadoop

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, jvm, benchmarking

I would like to employ JVM reuse to improve my Hadoop cluster's performance.

I ran the TestDFSIO benchmark with 100 files of 5MB on a single-node cluster, without and with JVM reuse (`mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks` set to `-1`).

I had system monitors running and JVM reuse significantly lowered the CPU usage. And supposedly, according to the benchmark results below, throughput went up.

However, the entire benchmark runtime barely changed. How is JVM reuse not improving the benchmark runtime, yet improving the throughput?

Without JVM Reuse:

```
13/10/29 12:27:07 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:        Number of files: 100
13/10/29 12:27:07 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Total MBytes processed: 500
13/10/29 12:27:07 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:      Throughput mb/sec: 37.310648459070215
13/10/29 12:27:07 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Average IO rate mb/sec: 42.019798278808594
13/10/29 12:27:07 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  IO rate std deviation: 10.420282152960008
13/10/29 12:27:07 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:     Test exec time sec: 325.443
```

With JVM Reuse:

```
13/10/29 12:35:29 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:        Number of files: 100
13/10/29 12:35:29 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Total MBytes processed: 500
13/10/29 12:35:29 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:      Throughput mb/sec: 55.17545795630104
13/10/29 12:35:29 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Average IO rate mb/sec: 69.57689666748047
13/10/29 12:35:29 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  IO rate std deviation: 21.605466270807376
13/10/29 12:35:29 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:     Test exec time sec: 330.218
```

Comment: Because your client is asynchronously coupled to the jobtracker, you don't get immediately back after a job is successful.

Comment: That still does not explain why there is *no* improvement in the benchmark runtime, especially given that there is so much discussion of the potential performance improvements with JVM reuse.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut To your comment, is there a way to change the async nature of the jobtracker?

Comment: The improvement is a higher throughput, nobody cares about the actual execution time which contains setup/cleanup and maybe even failure. Hadoop is not designed to be fast, but have linear scalability with high throughput. And yes, you can change the polling interval of the client and the tasktrackers- but this requires recompilation.

Comment: Did you run the test multiple times (with and without JVM reuse)? It is possible that you are not seeing an improvement, but rather just variability in results.

Comment: Yes, I verified my results multiple times.